# Is there a way to call api with only different sub domains in React?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, cross-domain, http-proxy-middleware

When I first did the React project, there was only one host domain api, so I used it by modifying the proxy value of the package file. (I prefer to use proxy because I suffered from cors problem.)

Recently, http-proxy-middleware was used to use more than two host domain api, and it has been used as follows.

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/call1', { target : 'http://sub.host1.com' }));
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/call2', { target : 'http://sub.host2.com' }));
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/call3', { target : 'http://sub.host3.com' }));
}
```

The problem is that I want to call same API, but with only the sub domain differently, but I don't know how.

**ex)**

**sub1.host1.com/call1**

**sub2.host1.com/call1**

**sub3.host1.com/call1**

Please let me know if you have any idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help.

```js
server.use(
  '/api',
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://sub.domain.com/',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': ''
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue with pathRewrite.

Comment: how? Could you show share your solution?

Comment: @NiuhuruLang

    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/a',{
        target:'https://aaa.com:9002/',
        secure:false,
        pathRewrite:{
            '^/a/' : '/'
        }
    }
    ))

    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/b',{
        target:'http://bbb/',
        secure:false,
        pathRewrite:{
            '^/b/' : '/'
        }
    }
    ))